# Can I override the companion object `apply` method from a Scala trait?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I want to restrict creation of a Scala class to use the companion object constructor:

```
case class Foo private (bar: String, baz: Int)
```

Now I can't use the `new` keyword; I can only create a foo like `Foo("catch", 22)`. But let's say I want to hook into the `apply` method on object creation to provide some additional functionality whenever an instance is created. Can I do that in the trait?

```
object Foo extends SpecialApply[Foo]

trait SpecialApply[C] {
  override def apply(args: ???) = ???
}
```

The central problem is that it seems like I don't know the constructor argument types (`String` and `Int`) in the trait. I could pass them in as a tuple, say, like this:

```
object Foo extends SpecialApply[(String, Int), Foo]

trait SpecialApply[A, C] {
  override def apply(args: ???) = <companion object>
}
```

Or I could get them by reflection. Either way, I'm not sure how to define the `apply` method over the tuple.

Is there some combination of reflection, `.tupled` functions, macro, and/or [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) magic that will make this work?

Comment: Do not forget about the `copy` methods either. You might also check https://github.com/propensive/magnolia as an alternative of shapeless for this task.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with trait. Even if you are willing to generate 22 traits like Scala standard library does for `Function`. you still will hit your own `private` wall: the constructor should be as inaccessible to your `SpecialApplyN` trait as it is for any other code. So you either have to put some code into specific companion objects anyway or to use reflection (which doesn't sound nice to me). Probably the only alternative to that is using some macro.